# How to realise "sumif" in python3.x within an csv data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i want to add up lines in a csv file (It's a BOM) if they are identical and in the same part, but not if they are a specific type. 
Here is the example to make it more clear:

```
LevelName,Type,Amount
Part_1,a,1
Part_1,a,1
Part_1,b,1
Part_1,c,1
Part_1,d,1
Part_1,f,1
Part_2,a,1
Part_2,c,1
Part_2,d,1
Part_2,a,1
Part_2,a,1
Part_2,d,1
Part_2,d,1
```

So i need to some up all Types within a Part but not if the type is 'd'.
Result should look like this:

```
LevelName,Type,Amount
Part_1,a,2
Part_1,b,1
Part_1,c,1
Part_1,d,1
Part_1,f,1
Part_2,a,3
Part_2,c,1
Part_2,d,1
Part_2,d,1
Part_2,d,1
```

unfortunatly i can not use any external lib. so pandas is no option here.

That is how far i got:

```
import csv
map = {}
with open('infile.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    with open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow(next(reader))
        for row in reader:
            (level, type, count) = row
            if not type=='d':
```

Well, here i just don't get ahead...
Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

master = {}
file = csv.DictReader(open(cwd+'\\infile.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
data = [row for row in file]

for row in data:
    master.setdefault(row['LevelName'], {})
    if row['Type'] != 'd':
        master[row['LevelName']].setdefault(row['Type'], 0)
        master[row['LevelName']][row['Type']] += int(row['Amount'])

print (master)
```

Not as simple as the soloution above but this shows how to iterate over the data

OR i suppose you could concatenate the 'LevelName' and the 'Type' so that you have one less line of code. It depends on what you what you want.

```
for row in data:
    if row['Type'] != 'd':
        master.setdefault(row['LevelName'] + row['Type'], 0)
        master[row['LevelName'] + row['Type']] += int(row['Amount'])

print (master)
```

EDIT

to write back to original format something like:

```
out = open(cwd+'\\outfile.csv', 'wb')
out.write('LevelName,Type,Amount\n')
for k,v in master.iteritems():
    for z in v:
        out.write('%s,%s,%s\n' % (k, z, str(v[z])))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. so this works as the result is returned: {'Part_1': {'f': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 2}, 'Part_2': {'c': 1, 'a': 3}}. What is breaking my head at the moment is how can i get it back to the original format? And what must i do if there are more columns that have to be copied as well?

Comment: See edit for writing back to original format. Does this answer the question? Upvote?

Comment: Yes it did. I can not upvote as i miss reputation. Thanks a lot!, ... just realized i can check!

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry about using pandas. Then first read the file saving the results in a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
grouped = defaultdict(int)

if not type=='d':
    grouped[(level, type)] += int(count)
```

Then you can save the result of that dict to a file

Comment: thanks, but i can not use pandas as i can not install it

Comment: I tried and failed due to: grouped[(level, type)] += count results in an error: "unsupported operand types for +=: 'int' and 'str'" Reading some stuff doesn't point me to a solution for this.

Comment: @himself `grouped[(level, type)] += int(count)` you'll read it as a string, and need to convert count to an integer

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As i am new to python i stick to less concentrated version below as i can understand it better. Thanks anyway!